# flutter: not subtype of type 'String' error. What should I correct?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

newbie here. Been trying to learn how to code during the quarantine period. I'm currently trying to create my first app. It's basically a weather app.

I think the error is coming from the displayBackground() method. I recently changed the code to get the sunrise and sunset from the 'sunrise_sunset.dart' package. 
Before this it was working, BUT I had hard-coded the sunrise and sunset times.

Thanks for the help.

CODE:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'GetLocation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:sunrise_sunset/sunrise_sunset.dart';

void main() => runApp(WeatherApp());

class WeatherApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeatherAppState createState() => _WeatherAppState();
}

class _WeatherAppState extends State<WeatherApp> {

  var apiKey = '****************************';
  var description;
  var temp;
  var city;
  var sunrise;

  var sunRise;
  var sunSet;
  var sunRiseEnd;
  var sunSetEnd;
  var formattedSunRise;
  var formattedSunSet;

  var sunRise_sunSet_time;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(displayBackground()),
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                child: Text(
                  'Your Location',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        '${city.toString()}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 50),
                    Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.location_on,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.wb_sunny,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$temp',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$description',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Get Weather Info',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          getLocation();
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // display background images based on current time
  displayBackground() async {
    var now = DateTime.now();

    sunRise = sunRise_sunSet_time.data.sunrise;
    sunSet = sunRise_sunSet_time.data.sunset;

    formattedSunRise = DateFormat.Hm().format(sunRise);
    formattedSunSet = DateFormat.Hm().format(sunSet);

    sunRiseEnd = sunRise.add(new Duration(hours: 1));
    sunSetEnd = sunSet.add(new Duration(hours: 1));

    print('im here...$formattedSunRise');
    print(formattedSunSet);

    if ( (now.isAfter(sunRise)) || (now.isBefore(sunRiseEnd)) ){
      print('Sun is rising');
    }else if((now.isAfter(sunRiseEnd)) || (now.isBefore(sunSet))){
      print('Day time');
    }else if((now.isAfter(sunSet)) || (now.isBefore(sunSetEnd))){
      print('Sun is setting');
    }else if((now.isAfter(sunSetEnd)) || (now.isBefore(sunRise))){
      print('Night time');
    }
  }

  //get location
  void getLocation() async {
    Getlocation getlocation = Getlocation();
    await getlocation.getCurrentLocation();

    print(getlocation.latitude);
    print(getlocation.longitude);
    print(getlocation.city);
    city = getlocation.city;
    getTemp(getlocation.latitude, getlocation.longitude);
  }

  //Get current temp
  Future<void> getTemp(double lat, double lon) async {


    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');
    // print(response.body);

    sunRise_sunSet_time = await SunriseSunset.getResults(date: DateTime.now(), latitude: 36.7201600, longitude: -4.4203400);

    var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
    description = dataDecoded['weather'][0]['description'];
    temp = dataDecoded['main']['temp'];
    sunrise = dataDecoded['sys']['sunrise'];
    print(temp);
    print(sunrise);
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
E/flutter (13644): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(213)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (13644): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.
E/flutter (13644): Receiver: null
E/flutter (13644): Tried calling: data
E/flutter (13644): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (13644): #1      _WeatherAppState.displayBackground (package:com/main.dart:132:35)
E/flutter (13644): #2      _WeatherAppState.build (package:com/main.dart:40:31)
E/flutter (13644): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
E/flutter (13644): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
E/flutter (13644): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (13644): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (13644): #7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2627:33)
E/flutter (13644): #8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:20)
E/flutter (13644): #9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (13644): #10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
E/flutter (13644): #11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
E/flutter (13644): #12     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:861:7)
E/flutter (13644): #13     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (13644): #14     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (13644): #15     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (13644): #16     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building WeatherApp(dirty, state: _WeatherAppState#7e657):
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
Reloaded 0 of 626 libraries in 164ms.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  WeatherApp file:///C:/Users/aldo0/Desktop/Learn_Flutter/my_weather_app/lib/main.dart:8:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _WeatherAppState.build (package:com/main.dart:40:31)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `sunRise_sunSet_time` being `null` when you try to access its data member. You have to make sure it is initialized beforehand.

I don't understand why you pass the `displayBackground()` method as parameter for an `AssetImage`. This widget takes a `String` representing the path of an image declared as an asset in your *pubspec.yaml* file.

As the code stands, you want to `await getTemp()` before ever calling `displayBackground()`, so that `sunRise_sunSet_time` is initialized.

Also, you want to call `setState((){})` every time you need your UI to update to reflect a change in the state. For example, in `getTemp()` because you change the `description` and `temp`:

```
setState(() {
    description = dataDecoded['weather'][0]['description'];
    temp = dataDecoded['main']['temp'];
    sunrise = dataDecoded['sys']['sunrise'];
});
```